# There was no endpoint listening at WcfPortal.svc that could accept the message

Tags: wcf, csla

I have a use case in my ASP.MVC app in which I need to save a collection of about 15k records (this is from a CSV file upload).  I'm putting it through CSLA business objects in order validate the uploaded data with business rules.

I'm making use of the WCF DataPortal. When save is called I get this error after about 30s to 45s:

System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at [my dataportal host address]/WcfPortal.svc that could accept the message.

I have determined that if I break down the collection into smaller chunks, and call save on each of those chunks, the use case completes without a problem.

I have configured my Service to use the max values as follows (recommended in Rocky's book) (and increased the sendTimeout based on other guidance):

```
<binding name="wsHttpBinding_IWcfPortal" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="05:00:00">  
    <readerQuotas maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"         maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647"/>
</binding>
```

Now I KNOW for a fact that my data does not exceed the 2147486347 size limit.  Besides, if it did, I would expect to get a more meaningful error message indicating this (like I did when the size limits were at their defaults).

I have turned on WCF logging/tracing, which reveals nothing.  This error seems to be some communication level error that gets hit before WCF stack comes into the picture.

Please advise as to why I would be getting this error when trying to save this large collection?

Answer (score 0):

As WCF has changed over the years they've added some other limits that you can change. The latest info on WCF configuration for the data portal is available in two places:

- The [data portal FAQ](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/faq/DataPortalFaq.ashx) page
- The [Using CSLA 4: Data Portal Configuration](http://store.lhotka.net/Default.aspx?tabid=1560&ProductID=26) ebook